# How to construct a Zend_Dojo xhrPost request

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to Dojo.

Please how do I construct an xhrPost request in Zend?

Answer (score 0):

I have used dojo for XhrPost for a while, it's really nice. There isn't much in the ZF manual but I've solved the communication by doing the client side as [dojo manual](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/xhrPost) suggests.

A little simplified my ajax class is:

```
dojo.declare('fetch_dom_node_contents', null, {
    handleAs: "json",

    load: function(response, ioArgs){
        this.ajax_response = response;
        this._loadModules();
        var dom_node = dojo.byId(response.node_name)
        dojo.html.set(dom_node, response.content);
        return response;
    },

    /**
     * Since modules might be needed for the new element they should be loaded
     */
    _loadModules: function(){
        if(this.ajax_response.dojo_modules){
            dojo.forEach(this.ajax_response.dojo_modules,
                function(mod){
                    dojo.require(mod);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

My controller is simple, by using the contextswitch I have the advantage of whenever in ajax JSON mode all the view variables are automatically converted to JSON format:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/application/my_classes.js');

        $contextSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch');
        $contextSwitch
                ->addActionContext('get-content', array('json'))
                ->setAutoJsonSerialization( true )
                ->initContext();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        //Stuff here ...
    }

    public function getContentAction(){
        $this->view->node_name = "my_node";
        $this->view->content = "Awesome content";
        $this->view->dojo_modules = $this->view->dojo()->getModules();
    }
}
```

Last I have the call to the get-content:

```
dojo.xhrGet(new fetch_dom_node_contents("/index/get-content/format/json"));
```

This I usaully embed in som  or button onClick() event. Important is to have the:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

Before the xhrGet() or xhrPost(). If your posting forms all you have to do is add the form: dojo.byId("myform") in the fetch_dom_node_contents class and the form is sent to your controller where you just handle it as "business as usual".

Since a ajax submitted form usually redirects or does something else you should attach "/format/json" or something similar to hint to the action that it should return a json as a response and not a just do a redirect. I have this simple action helper for checking if I'm in an ajax call or not:

```
<?php

/**
 * Action Helper for checking if context is of json type
 *
 * @uses Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
 */
class Action_Helper_IsJson extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
        /**
         * Checks if the format parameter is set to json
         * if so it returns true
         * 
         */
        public function isJson(){
                $format = $this->getRequest()->getParam('format', false);
                if (strtolower($format) == "json"){
                        return true;
                }else{
                        return false;
                }
        }

        public function direct()
        {
                return $this->isJson();
        }
}
```

When my form is successfully parsed I have another helper that is convenient whenever there's a redirect:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @uses Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
 */
class Action_Helper_SendReloadResponse extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
        /**
         */
        public function sendReloadResponse($url){
                echo Zend_Json_Encoder::encode(array(
                        'success' => true,
                        'reloadHTTP' => $url)
                );
                die();
        }

        /**
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function direct($url)
        {
                return $this->sendReloadResponse($url);
        }
}
```

I then have in my ajax load part a:

```
if (responseData.reloadHTTP) {
    // Probably first element or last element
    window.location = responseData.reloadHTTP;
}
```

Hmm... I don't know if this is the best way of dealing with the xhrGet/Post but it works fine and perhaps you can fiddle around with it, find better solutions and share - I didn't find that much when wanted to start with ajax, dojo and zend. One that got me started was [nanaeu](http://naneau.nl/2007/05/19/on-input-validation-2/) but that code (as mine) is pretty old by now :/

Answer (score 0):

I have a much simpler method.

In view script

```
<?php $this->dojo()->javascriptCaptureStart() ?>
function ajaxUpdate(url, targetNode, p1, p2) {
    // remove old content, prevents id clashing when generating new content.
    dojo.forEach(dijit.findWidgets(targetNode), function(win) {
        win.destroyRecursive();   
    });
    var xhrArgs = {
        url: url,
        handleAs: "text",
        content: {
            p1: p1,
            p2: p2
        },
        load: function(data) {
            dojo.html.set(targetNode, data, {parseContent: true});
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("An unexpected error occurred: " + error);
        }
    }
    dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
}
<?php $this->dojo()->javascriptCaptureEnd() ?>
```

You could also add that to the layout script or even the bootstrap file if you do a lot of AJAX and want it to appear in every view.

Now lets you have a button with id="show-message" in your view and you want to load custom html base on the values of an input field (id="field1") and a checkbox (id="box1") into a div (id="put-message-here"). Then you would set the following also in the view script:

```
<?php $this->dojo()->onLoadCaptureStart() ?>
 function() {
    var field1 = dojo.byId("field1").value;
    var box1 = dojo.byId("box1").value;
    var url = "/module/controller/action/format/html";
    var targetNode = dojo.byId("put-message-here");

    dojo.connect(dojo.byId("show-message"), 'onclick', function() {
        ajaxUpdate(url, targetNode, field1, box1);
    });
 }
<?php $this->dojo()->onLoadCaptureEnd() ?>
```

The in the url would would replace the module, controller, action with whatever ones point to your action to handle the ajax call. If you don't have modules setup then it needs to be set to "default", omitting it doesn't seem to work.

So if we had set url = "/default/index/ajaxform/format/html" then in our indexController:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        // set actions for use with AJAX call.
        $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
        $ajaxContext->addActionContext('ajaxform', 'html')
                    ->initContext();
    }

    public function ajaxformAction()
    {
        $field = $this->getRequest()->getParam('p1');
        $box = $this->getRequest()->getParam('p2');

        // logic goes here

        $this->view->some_var = $whatever;
    }

    ....
```

As you can see, our action looks like any other action in Zend. The only difference is that instead of sending its out put to ajaxform.phtml, it sends it to ajaxform.ajax.phtml (because of the helper used in the init(). So now in ajaxform.ajax.phtml you'd have whatever code you want to display inside our target div.

```
<p><?php echo $this->some_var; ?></p>
```

Again looks like any other viewscript.

The only catch I've found is that any new dojo dijits I want to create have to be created declaratively, meaning I can't use the dojo view helpers.